# R - How to find the Intersection fo 2 Functions

Tags: r, intersection

I have 2 functions and I would like to find the values at which their intersect and plot it on the graph. How can I best achieve this? Does anyone know an R function for that?

```
# First Function
  func6 <- function(x)
    {
    x * log(x) - sqrt(x)
  }

  # Second Function
  func7 <- function(x)
    {
    x
  }

  x <- seq(0,10,length=100)
  plot(x, func6(x), col="blue", lwd="1", main="Graph #1")
  lines(x, func7(x), col="red")
```

Comment: Are you looking for the area spanned by both `func6` and `func7` or do you want to get the `x` values where `func6(x) = func7(x)`?

Comment: I am looking for a stable point of func6, and this translates into solving for the intersection of func6 and f(x) = x (which is func7()).

Comment: `uniroot(function(x)  x * log(x) - sqrt(x) - x , c(.01,10))  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uniroot` to search for the intersection; this equates to searching for the zero of the difference of the functions.

```
rt <- uniroot(function(x)  func6(x) - func7(x)  , c(.01,10), tol=1e-8)     
# or explicitly
# rt <- uniroot(function(x)  x * log(x) - sqrt(x) - x , c(.01,10), tol=1e-8)  

# check
all.equal(func6(rt$root), func7(rt$root))  
# [1] TRUE
```

Then plot it

```
x <- seq(0, 10, length=100)
plot(x, func6(x), col="blue", lwd="1", main="Graph #1", type="l")
lines(x, func7(x), col="red")
points(rt$root, rt$root, pch=16, cex=2, col="red")
```

As pointed out by K.Troy, in the general case the y-coordinate should be transformed : *"The second argument to the points function should be to invoke either func6 or func7 using rt$root"*

```
points(rt$root, func6(rt$root), pch=16, cex=2, col="red")
```

Comment: @K.Troy: `func6(rt$root)` is the same as `rt$root` as one  function is y=x

Comment: @K.Troy ; i was a bit quick there sorry, I have updated. Thanks